# Dismissviewcontroller to another view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Lets say I have View: A, and B on a tab bar. View B when clicking a button it opens View C with a modal segue (I did this to avoid losing the tab bar with push segue after returning from this view controller). I want to dismiss view controller C, and instead of getting B, I want to get view controller A. How could I accomplish this in Swift?

Comment: Simply modify the `selectedViewController` property on your UITabBarController instance to select view A when required

Comment: @Paulw11 could you please link me to how i could do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
func backTwoViewController() {
    let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController];
    self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2], animated: true); 
}
```

or if your View A is the rootViewController and you could use the following:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: 1. fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2. Nothing happens.

Comment: do you have navigationcontroller which is attached View A?

Comment: @casillas Why are you messing with a navigation controller when it is the tab bar controller that needs to be manipulated?